# How do I periodically run a command with very short interval and get the return?

Tags: command-line

I need to call a specific command in an interval of about 5 sec. How would I setup a daemon/process running in the background or something similar to do that? I looked at cronjobs, but the minimum interval seems to be 1 minute. Any advice is appreciated ;)

Fedora is the system.

EDIT
the command would be a bashscript, so "watch" wouldn´t do it I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(
  while true
  do
    your-command-here
    sleep 5
  done
) &
disown
```

Comment: what is disown for? what if I run without it?

Comment: @Marcel, `disown` removes the last job from the shell job table, making it sort of a daemon, like you asked. It is not a real daemon because it is still attached to terminal and is in the same process group, but it will keep running after you close the shell.

Comment: okay great, that would work :D Just for curiosity how would i "make" a daemon?

Comment: @Marcel the simple way is to call [daemon(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) from C or other language with library access (not from a shell script). [This is the hard way](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html).

Answer (score 14):

Why do you think 'watch' will not work?

```
$ cat periodic.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date)
$ chmod +x periodic.sh
```

---

```
$ watch -n 5 ./periodic.sh
```

Comment: what if I log out? the script should continue running.

Comment: It will stop, but you can use `nohup watch -n 5 ./periodic.sh > periodic.log &` and store the output.

Comment: for piping use the '' quoting because th "command is given to "sh -c" which means that you may need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with nohup? It's designed to let a job run after the shell is closed.

You can also use screens.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` command is appropriate in your case, i would use a terminal multiplexer (e.g. tmux, screen, etc.) and then run the command using

```
watch -n 5 ./script.sh
```

In that case even if you close the terminal or ssh connection to the machine the script would still be running.

The only limitation of this approach is that the script will run every 5 seconds only if it has completed its execution within that time interval.

Comment: Since the OP explicitly stated that in his opinion `watch` wouldn't do it, please explain why your answer overcomes this limitation or at which point you think the OP was mistaken about `watch` being unsuitable for the task.